# DropBox : downloading file by parts?

Tags: amazon-s3, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there a way to download parts of file using drop box API? Which could be useful in cases when files could be very large. I would like to transfer files to AWS S3 from DropBox but I don't want to copy the file to local hard-drive since that would take much longer than keeping the stream in memory and would possibly fill up the hard-drive with temporary files if there are multiple large files being transferred from DropBox to S3 at the same time.

When looking at the drop box java SDK (1.7.7) `DbxClient`
has a method which would seem to do what I want 
`public Downloader startGetFile(final String path, String rev)`

However the `Downloader` that is given back only has one public method `DbxEntry.File copyBodyAndClose(OutputStream target)`

Answer (score 1):

Using the Java SDK, I would think that `getFile` does what you need. It takes an `OutputStream` as a parameter, so you could start your HTTP request to S3, get an output stream to write to S3, and pass that stream to `getFile`.

**EDIT**: Here's the [link](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#getFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)) to `getFile`.

**EDIT2**: I should also point out that [`/files (GET)`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET) does support HTTP range retrieval requests, so you can download in whatever chunks you want too.